# how to update a single file in SVN

Tags: svn

I want to check-out and check-in a single file. I tried the command below but it did not work:

```
svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth empty
```

When I tried below command it worked.

```
svn export <url_of_big_dir> <target>
```

But I read in some documents it is not proper to use Export when your requirement is to update a file.

How do I update a single file?

Answer (score 11):

Check out the directory, and only the directory (via `--depth=empty`), that contains the file:

```
svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth=empty
```

Next, go into the checked out target and update just the file you want:

```
cd <target>
svn update <filename>
```

Here, `<filename>` is relative to `<url_of_big_dir>`.  From here, you can modify and commit it as normal.

The `export` command creates an unversioned copy of the file, which means you can't commit it back to the repository.  If you don't need to do this, then export is fine and you can do it in one command:

```
svn export <url_of_big_dir>/<filename>
```

Comment: with export i can get single file. but i cannot commit that file.

Comment: svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth files --> we get all the files under that directory.

Comment: but with svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth empty it will checkout all the subdirectories and files..

Comment: `svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth=empty` will only check out <url_of_big_dir>.  Check [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) if you don't believe me.  What you describe is `--depth=infinity`.

Comment: @viki you have `--depth empty` in stead of `--depth=empty` in your comment. You don't have the equal sign in between